# Register page not store data in the database

Tags: php

I have a problem with the register page in PHP language. When I click the submit button the form is submitting but no data is storing in the database. And can not use the registered user to login into the site. The same codes are working properly in the local server (Wampp server) but not working in the website.
these are the codes:

```
    <?php
require_once("../includes/functions.php");
$sess_start->start_session(false);
if(check_login(1, $sess_start->get_dbhandler()) == true)
{
    header('Location: userportal.php');
}
else
{
    if (!empty($_POST['RegisterFname']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterLname']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterEmail']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterUsername']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterPassword']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterRPassword']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterDob']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterAddress']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterRegion']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterCountry']) || !empty($_POST['RegisterPhone']))
    {
        if (!empty($_POST['RegisterFname']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterLname']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterEmail']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterUsername']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterPassword']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterRPassword']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterDob']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterAddress']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterRegion']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterCountry']) && !empty($_POST['RegisterPhone']))
        {
            if (($_POST['RegisterPassword'] == $_POST['RegisterRPassword']))
            {
                if (strlen($_POST['RegisterRPassword']) >= 8)
                {
                    $registeruser = new user();
                    $registeruser->nickname = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterUsername']);
                    $registeruser->sql = mysqli_query($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE n_name = '$registeruser->nickname'");

                    if (mysqli_num_rows($registeruser->sql) == 0)
                    {   
                        $registeruser->fname = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterFname']);
                        $registeruser->lname = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterLname']);
                        $registeruser->email = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterEmail']);
                        $registeruser->password = $_POST['RegisterRPassword'];
                        $registeruser->password = hash('sha512', $registeruser->password);
                        $registeruser->dob = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterDob']);
                        $registeruser->addr = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterAddress']);
                        $registeruser->state = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterRegion']);
                        $registeruser->country = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterCountry']);
                        $registeruser->phone = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterPhone']);
                        $registeruser->regtime = time();
                        $registeruser->sql = mysqli_query($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), "INSERT INTO `users` (f_name, l_name, email, n_name, password, age, addr, state, country, phone, l_login, r_time) VALUES ('$registeruser->fname', '$registeruser->lname', '$registeruser->email', '$registeruser->nickname', '$registeruser->password', '$registeruser->dob', '$registeruser->addr', '$registeruser->state', '$registeruser->country', '$registeruser->phone', '0', '$registeruser->regtime')");
                        if (!empty($_GET['RegisterPromo']))
                        {   
                            $registeruser->coupon = clean_string($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), $_POST['RegisterPromo']);
                            $registeruser->sql = mysqli_query($sess_start->get_dbhandler(), "UPDATE `users` SET promo = '$registeruser->coupon' WHERE n_name = '$registeruser->nickname'");
                        }
                        $_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] = 5;
                        header('Location: register.php');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] = 4;
                        header('Location: register.php');
                    }                           
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] = 3;
                    header('Location: register.php');
                }   
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] = 2;
                header('Location: register.php');
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] = 1;
            header('Location: register.php');
        }       
    }
    else
    {   
        echo '
        meta tages and links for the stylesheets
        ';
        ?>

        <?php

        ?>
        <div class="container" id="registration-form">
            <div class="image"></div>
        <form role="form" class="form-signin" method="post" action="<?php echo clean_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
        <section class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['RegisterUserError']))
        {
            if ($_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] == 1)
            {   
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                <strong>Fill all mandatory fields(*) for completing user registeration</strong>
                </div>  
                <?php
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] == 2)
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                <strong>Entered passwords do not match</strong>
                </div> 
                <?php
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] == 3)
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                <strong>Passwords must be 8 or more character longer</strong>
                </div> 
                <?php
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] == 4)
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                <strong>There is already a user exist with this same username</strong>
                </div> 
                <?php
            }
            else if ($_SESSION['RegisterUserError'] == 5)
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                <strong>Successfully completed the user registeration. However, your account is not verified unless you complete "Know your customer" process after login to your account.</strong>
                </div> 
                <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-block alert-danger fade in">
                <strong>Unexpected error occured</strong>
                </div> 
                <?php
            }   
            unset($_SESSION['RegisterUserError']);
        }
        else
        {   
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
            <strong>Fields indicated using * are mandatory in registeration</strong>
            </div>  
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="frm">
            inputs here
        </form>
        <div class="form-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                    <i class="fa fa-check"></i> <a href="login.php"> Sign In </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
        <?php

    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Anyhting on the error log?

Comment: Just asking, but is your DB connection string valid? Server, username, password, db name? Everything alright?

Comment: Nothing in the error log

Comment: Yes the DB connection is valid, the same codes are working in the local server

Comment: I think you haven't include class at top before calling; $registeruser = new user(); From where you initiate the $registeruser object.

Answer (score 0):

if it is working on your local server, then check your web hosting service. Most Service provider will ask you to the these three things :
1.Create the database
2.Create a database user
3.Assign the user to the database

These steps could be confusing depending on your host and is usually carried out in your cpanel database page or use the database creation wizard if available.

Comment: I created the database and the user and I assigned the user to the database with all privileges